# Is it cruel to take a cat inside for one or two days due to cold?

Tags: cats, psychology, strays

There are several stray cats outside and currently the weather is around 0 C. We expect it to get colder at night. The temperature is expected to be around -10 C during the night.

While I expect all the cats to survive this, [thanks to the cat houses of the municipalities](https://listelist.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/guzelkedievi-uskudar.jpg) and getting fed regularly, despite being strays, I believe I can ease one of the younger cats with a day of warmth. But in no condition this can be permanent, I think of taking one in for the night, at most for two nights.

Will this result in an attachment and heart break on the cat? Is this cruel in any way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My rabbits can handle temperatures to -15°C before I need to take them in. They are 3 and would cuddle themself together in a small house they can heat with their own body. So I would assume that cats have similar skills with the provided cat houses :)

Comment: @Allerleirauh I am sure they will survive, they also start cuddling together at one point. But I can still slightly help one of them.

Comment: You could perhaps build a shelter outside, if you have room for that

Comment: @Berend Yes, a save warm place with open "door" to the outside would suit for this also. The cat wouldn't see a "take inside" without escape as something good :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I suspect the biggest risk factor will be the attachment of the human, not the cat ;).

If the cat is familiar with you and your home and follows you willingly, I see no reason why you couldn't keep it from the cold occasionally. However, if the cat wants to go outside and you don't let it, that could lead to stress and do more harm that good. Depending on the character of the cat, it might be afraid or search for an exit the entire night. If you had let it outside, it would have gotten a good night's sleep, although a little cold.

The question is: How will *you* feel? Will you be happy to see the cat leaving your home for the day? Will *you* start letting it sleep inside every day? Will *you* feed it every day? Then the cat becomes dependent on you and might have serious disadvantages if you ever cannot care for it (maybe due to an illness) or move away temporarily (like on a holiday) or permanently.